# Which is the best way to choose a template based on a ng-model property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say we have a person object with a few "person-properties"

```
personModel = {
 membership-number : "abcd",
 name : "Anonymous",
 dob : "14/04/2009",
 avatar : "image.png"
}
```

Let's also say we have metadata about these "person-properties".

```
meta-data = {
 membership-number: {data-type : "string", editable : "false"},
 name : {data-type : "string", editable : "true"},
 dob : {data-type : "date", editable : "true"},
 avatar : {data-type : "image", editable : "true"}
}
```

Now I would like to list these properties of the personModel on a page with the following constraints.
member-ship name which is string and non-editable, should be displayed as a label.
All editable strings as text box, all date types with a date-picker, etc.

I know this can be done with angular directives. Have a directive called person which will iterate through the "person-properties" of the personObject.

```
<person ng-model={{personModel}}> </person>
```

and have a directive for each "person-property" inside the person, like :

```
<person-property ng-repeat = {{prop in person-properties}}> </person-property>
```

Let's also assume that the property directive has access to the metadata.
To get templates based on the property-type, I can write if-else in the person-property's definition to choose which template to return, like this skeleton.

```
if(property_type === "date"){
   template = "<datepicker> </datepicker>"
}
else if (property-type === "numeric"){
   template = "<numeric-editable-box> </numeric-editable-box>"
}
```

But is there a more elegant way to do this?

WPF has something called TemplateSelector to do this. Does angular have something similar that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `ng-switch` may fit your needs.
switch on the meta data and display appropriate elements.

```
<div ng-switch="property_type">
  <datepicker when="date"></datepicker>
  <numeric-editable-box when="numeric"></numeric-editable-box>
</div>
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good approach.  I recently wrote about this technique for dynamically selecting custom directives, based on an iteration of data.  http://whatsthebigit.blogspot.com/2013/07/dynamic-directives-with-angular.html